# Deleting Safari cookies programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cookies, safari

OSX Sierra 10.12.1 Safari 10.0.1

I am attempting to reproduce the behaviour of the MacOS Safari->Preferences->Privacy->ManageWebsiteData->RemoveAll button programmatically in deleting all website data, however, the data always seems to persist. A number of SO threads suggest something along these lines using the HTTPCookieStorage class:

```
if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {
    cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.sharedCookieStorage(forGroupContainerIdentifier: "Cookies")
} else {
    cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
}
cookieJar.removeCookies(since: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1))
```

Using [this](http://securitylearn.net/wp-content/uploads/tools/iOS/BinaryCookieReader.py) binary cookie reader python script I can validate the expected result in ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies

I have also validated operations such as cookieJar.setCookie() and cookieJar.deleteCookie() makes changes within this store and that cookieJar.cookies is as expected.

I also added this call based on a couple of other SO threads I came across:

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

After executing this code, website data continues to be persisted. Safari->Preferences->Privacy->ManageWebsiteData is seemingly uneffected.

I've also tried following guidance from here and performed this operation with Safari closed since this could be achieved programmatically using the FileManager class:
https://www.macissues.com/2015/06/22/how-to-fully-reset-safari-on-your-mac/

The website data still persisted. Does anyone know of any further steps that need to be taken to fully remove all website data?

Answer (score 0):

This removes the cookies for your app. E.g. `NSURLSession` calls or `WKWebView` are affected by this. You can't remove user's cookies from another app (Safari). If you could this would be a privacy/malware concern.

If this is not a sandboxed app, you can probably just remove the files in Safari's sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for Safari sandbox suggestion, I will give that a try. The [API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage) seemed to imply this restriction only applied to iOS rather than OSX where cookie storage is shared (except where sessionOnly=TRUE).

Comment: I tried the sandbox suggestion and also removed a few other items in the hope of effecting the website data that is displayed:
`~/Library/Safari` 

`~/Library/Cookies` 

`~Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari` 

The Safari website data still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AppleScript to click the Remove All button.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"

    -- Display the preferences privacy tab
    keystroke "," using command down
    delay 1
    click button "Privacy" of toolbar 1 of window 1

    -- Display the cookie list  
    click button "Manage Website Data…" of group 1 of group 1 of window "Privacy"
    delay 3
    click button "Remove All"
    click button "Done"

end tell
```

Obviously this has the disadvantage that the user can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bruce. I discounted applescript for the reason you stated, but still, the script is nice and concise and works way better than one I had contrived myself. I eventually ended up manipulating the Safari preferences to only open private browser windows but again, this is also susceptible to the user overriding the setting. FWIW, the aim of this was experimenting with adding a multiple user profile support on top of Safari leveraging the new extension architecture but I have been unable to ensure there is no leakage between those profiles because of the cookie limitation.

Comment: Ah. I think you are always going to struggle with that because Safari is designed to be single user - it is MacOS that is multi-user and everything expects each user to have their own account. You could try abusing the 'sudo' command, e.g.:

Comment: [Sorry - edits timed out while I was checking syntax ]

$ sudo -u Guest "open -a Safari"

You'll need to fiddle with the sudoers file to get the permissions right.